# How to click the last radiobutton using Watin

Tags: c#, watin

I use Watin for the automation work and it work well for me. Today, I encounter ont issue and have no idea of it:

I want to click the last radiobox in the page. And all "input" elemens with "radio" type have the same "name" and "id", as below.

```
<input name="rd_addr_id" id="rd_new_addr" type="radio" value="-1"/>
```

How can i get the constraint? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried multiple Find.By clauses like:

```
ie.RadioButton(Find.ByName("rd_addr_id") && Find.ById("rd_new_addr") 
    && Find.ByValue("-1")).Click();
```

Hope it helps